# What are these absurd errors in apache log?

Tags: php, apache, drupal-7, coredump, error-log

I´m getting hundreds of these errors in the apache log in a website with around 4000 visits per hour. I have never seen any evidence of these errors affecting user experience in the website, but i believe it may be happening 1 in 100 requests or something like that, making it very difficult to diagnose.

These messages are really absurd as for what they say they should be killing the requests generating bad user experience, and DRUPAL_ROOT is defined in index.php, so how can it already be defined if it is called only once in the execution thread?

I've seen these errors are almost always close to a Core Dump error record. Any complete theories about what could be happening here?

And drupal_bootstrap not defined right after "require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';" how is this possible?

Have anyone seen this happen before?

These are the errors I see in the log:

```
PHP Notice: Constant DRUPAL_ROOT already defined in /var/www/vhosts/hsbnoticias/index.php on line 17, referer: http://diariodelsur.com.co/noticias/judicial

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function drupal_bootstrap() in /var/www/vhosts/hsbnoticias/index.php on line 20, referer: http://diariodelsur.com.co/noticias/judicial
```

I´m using a 6GB Linde Ubuntu LAMP Single Server, with around 300 to 400 apache preforked processes. The website seems to be working fine, so no errors are being reported by vistors, no evidence of errors in analytics, and haven´t seen these popping up in the client side my self.

Comment: The notice is just a notice. You try to declare DRUPAL_ROOT twice. The second time fails, but doesn't affect the script. Only that line is skipped. The fatal error will end the script right away, and may have effect on user experience. Since these errors are both in the first 20 lines of index.php, can you post that chunk of code (say, line 1 to 25)? Maybe some Drupal afficionados can tell if you did anything wrong.

Comment: If you don't get any answer here, you can try there: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Core Dump is bad, something crashed, you need to find out what crashed. You should be able to load the core dump with ```gdb /path/to/apache /path/to/core```. IMO this question doesn't belong here, it would be better on superuser ...

Comment: The core dumps are being caused by the linux OOM killer, so that's actually a good behavior when there is no more memory available, but there is no way DRUPAL_ROOT is declared twice in drupal index.php as it appears only once there. I tried this question in drupal exchange but they didn't seem to like it: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/177641/weird-drupal-errors-in-apache-log

Comment: Here is the Drupal index.php for reference: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/index.php?h=7.x

Comment: I posted the question again in superuser, as per Joe Watkins suggestion. http://superuser.com/questions/991885/what-are-these-absurd-errors-in-apache-log